# importerror when I use pathos

Tags: python, python-2.7, pathos

I try to use pathos for multiprocessing，but when I start the
process, I get the `ImportError:no module named pp`，please help me.
I download pathos from github, install by python setup.py, `python version 2.7.8`,

Comment: Did you try `import pathos.pools as pp` ?

Comment: could you show us the full traceback and the relevant code?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the `pathos` author.  `pathos` has a few dependencies, and if you are installing `pathos` by hand (as you are doing now), you have to get all of the dependencies for it fully work.

The easiest thing to do is to use `pip`, and `pip install pathos`.
Or, you can first install `setuptools`, and then repeat what you already have done (install by hand), and `setuptools` will grab and install the dependencies for you.

Or if you do want to do everything the hard way… then you need to install `dill`, `pox`, `ppft`, and `multiprocess`.  Install them before installing `pathos`.

It's typically much much easier if you have `setuptools` installed.